# best implementation of splash screen Android

Tags: android, kotlin, layout, splash-screen, drawable

Looking online I've found more than one way to implement a splash screen on Android apps. Someone create a new "splashActivity" with a "splash.xml" layout and a "splash_theme" (often fullscreen), some others use a "splashActivity" with no "splash.xml" layout, but just a theme with a "splashscreenDrawable.xml" as background. I'm using the last one because it seems more fast compared to the first case (maybe the theme+drawable is not heavy as the layout?), but which is better? In which cases should I use the first or the second one?

The app uses android oreo 8.0 and I'm using kotlin

This is the code (just in case the question is not well expressed sry)

MainActivity.kt (do nothing)

```
package com.example.mobileprogrammingproject

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml (just a test layout with a tv and a btn)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:textSize="26sp">
        </TextView>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="press me"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titleTextView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">
        </Button>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

SplashScreen.kt (the launcher activity that calls the MainActivity.kt)

```
package com.example.mobileprogrammingproject

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler


class SplashScreen : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        startActivity(Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java))
        finish()
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml (i've changed the laucher activity from MainActivity.kt to SplashScreen.kt)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mobileprogrammingproject">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/icon"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MobileProgrammingProject">

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen" android:theme="@style/SplashScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        </activity>

    </application>
```

and the splash theme (using a drawable)

```
<style
    name="SplashScreen" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen_drawable</item>
    
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

this is the splash_screen_drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/splash_background_color"
        android:drawable="@android:color/black" />
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/dicce_logo"
            android:gravity="center"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: Well, you answered your own question. The best implementation is to use a theme instead of a new activity. A SplashScreen serves to show something WHILE the app is loading. Using another activity for this purpose just extends the app loading state, which is not wanted

Answer (score 0):

The use of the two modes is completely left to the developer as he is the only one who knows what the app must do before starting and above all he decides the flow to follow.

Personally I can tell you that the spash screen created by xml, style etc. is the one suggested for everything because you have the right waiting time for the start (about a second) and you have the opportunity to have a unique experience for the user who interface with yours instead of with the most famous and used apps.

Someone implements the class with xml layout etc in case they want to manage the splash duration based on services and actions that they need to check or validate before bringing the user into the app.